# How radioactive could I make some materials, while keeping them "cold"?

Tags: chemistry, radiation

I have some radioactive alien ruins on an icy planet. Radiation means energy is being emitted and particles are moving about, which would heat up the surrounding area. I would like to maximize the radiation, while minimizing this heat.

How high can I go on the radiation scale without compromising the "icyness" of my planet?

Comment: Highly radioactive = short life. Long life = weakly radioactive. The point being that unless the ruins are less than a century old, or are made of solid natural uranium, they will probably be sufficiently weakly radioactive for the heat to have little noticeable effect on the ice which is not actually *touching* them.

Comment: "Icy planet" covers a *lot* of ground, from just cold enough to freeze water down to the freezing point of nitrogen. The further you are from room temperature, the more radioactivity you'd need to be noticeable.

Answer (score 13):

Your ruins can readily emit enough radiation to be quickly lethal to humans, without being noticeably above ambient temperature.

One way this might occur is to have heavy contamination with a gamma emitter like Cobalt 60.  Gamma interacts very little with water/ice, and its emission leaves little heat energy in the emitter, but it's used in irradiation sterilization because it can very quickly kill *everything with DNA* -- without having bad effects on, for instance, airtight packaging, structures, or shielding material.

In fact, gamma or x-ray emission is the primary way radiation is highly lethal (alpha is just too easy to shield against, and beta -- electrons and positrons -- interacts too strongly with matter to travel far in atmosphere).  Many gamma emitters, however, are also undergoing alpha and beta decay, both of which deposit energy (which quickly becomes heat) in the emitter and anything close to it.  Cobalt 60 is unusual in this respect, in terms of emitting gamma with little other emission.

Downside is, with a half life of just over five years, a Cobalt-60 gamma source that would have literally glowed in the dark from fluorescence of irradiate material when deposited will be barely radioactive after as little as a single century.  For the ruins to emit gamma from Cobalt-60, then, they'd have to be quite recent, or there would have to be constant replenishment of the Cobalt-60 source -- which would be accompanied by other decays that would still produce lots of plain old thermal heat.

Another potential source of radiation without heat, potentially not coming from the ruins themselves, is synchrotron radiation.  This is what's produced for free electron lasers, and it can have wavelengths from long IR (potentially as long as microwaves) to the hardest gamma measurable, depending on the tuning of the "wiggler".  This, however, would require an operating energy source to keep the particle accelerator and wiggler magnets operating -- but those need not be inside the ruins, as a gamma laser could be fairly quickly lethal from tens of kilometers through air.

Comment: If you were to combine the two (at this time) answers, perhaps Cobalt-59 is slowly brought up from the depths of the planet, and while it does so it happens to pass by a naturally-occurring nuclear reactor (e.g. Oklo), whose neutron radiation actives some of the Co-59 to Co-60.

Answer (score 3):

**Neutron radiation.**

Your ruins emit neutron radiation.  The ruins are not that massive and so most of the neutrons are emitted into the atmosphere, where they travel large distances before dropping off heat.

https://www.nrc.gov/about-nrc/radiation/health-effects/radiation-basics.html

> Neutrons are high-speed nuclear particles that have an exceptional
> ability to penetrate other materials. Of the five types of ionizing
> radiation discussed here, neutrons are the only one that can make
> objects radioactive. This process, called neutron activation, produces
> many of the radioactive sources that are used in medical, academic,
> and industrial applications (including oil exploration).
>
> Because of their exceptional ability to penetrate other materials,
> neutrons can travel great distances in air and require very thick
> hydrogen-containing materials (such as concrete or water) to block
> them. Fortunately, however, neutron radiation primarily occurs inside
> a nuclear reactor, where many feet of water provide effective
> shielding.

The ruins themselves contain various radioactive elements which have been produced over time by the neutron radiation bombarding the materials of the ruins.  Also materials comprising the ruins have been transmuted to a variety of other elements via neutron radiation.

Answer (score 1):

**Long underground heatpipes away from the city**

That city used to be a high-tech gathering with a LOT of computing power. They purposefully set up on an ice planet because that'd allow them easy cooling. But how to cool the cheapest (on a very long term scale)? Passively. They just dug lines of huge [heat pipes](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Heat_pipe) throughout the entire planet. Because heat that would strangle a city still hardly matters when spread over an entire (or half of) a planet.

And compared to the server farms of old, that bit of energy that your radiation gives off is miniscule. Yes, the city is warmer than the rest, but -20 C vs -25 everywhere else isn't that relevant a difference for most organisms

Answer (score 1):

**A matter of scale**

Because of square-cube effect, the bigger a radioactive item is, the hotter it is (and even hotter inside). The Earth (as a whole) is quite hot inside (we have a molten ocean of iron and rock underground) while all of the materials that heat it are safe to touch and live with.

At the other end of the scale, airborne dust or dust settled on otherwise non-radioactive items can be extremely radioactive (deadly in minutes or hours) without heating its surroundings measurably. This is what we get after a nuclear bomb or a nuclear plant disaster.

What are the possible problems for your plot:

1. Ice/snow is a good radiation shield. Dust can get buried in the snow and be dangerous only if excavated.
2. "Hot" isotopes don't live for long and you need really big amount of the long-lived ones. You need either a precise timing or a plausible source for the big amount of long-lived isotopes.

Answer (score 1):

**Intermittent critical events**

Small pieces of plutonium can be handled by humans without major ill effects and they don't produce much heat. But it's very insidious because when the pieces are placed together and reach critical mass, the chain reaction starts quickly and easily delivers lethal doses. Not even the plutonium itself needs to be moved, it is sufficient that it gets surrounded by water which slows neutrons, then more of them react.

The problem seems barely tractable even under lab settings as described below, now imagine unwary explorers in alien city with such nasty materials strewn around:
https://www.science.org/content/article/near-disaster-federal-nuclear-weapons-laboratory-takes-hidden-toll-america-s-arsenal